# Laravel searching for Arabic string inside Json

Tags: php, sql, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hello I have a *project* table which has a field *name* in my db which is multi lang so I stored it as json so I can store each lang value 
the problem is that the arabic lang is being encoded in this way:

```
{"ar":"\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0634\u0631\u0648\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0648\u0644"}
```

and im trying to search the project by name in arabic 
I tried json endcoding the string before seaching the db didnt work 
I tried even to searching in mysql or the string:
[image]

also didnt work ... any idea?

Comment: If it's in a database and you need to search for it, then it should be a properly defined and encoded column, not hidden inside of a JSON blob.

Answer (score 0):

decode the string after getting from database :

```
$result = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

then get the arabic data

```
$text = $result['ar'];
```

then again decode the encoded string

```
echo $finalanswer = json_decode('"' . $text . '"');
```